# @KafkaListener fall into an infinite loop after the kafka cluster is down

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka cluster with 3 nodes, and I use debezium(a kafka-mysql connector).
I write a method with `@KafkaListener` as a topic consumer.
Then I manually shutdown the kafka cluster(kill -15).

Then the listener suddenly fall into an infinite loop.

**Top Command**

[image]

**jstack**

[image]

**And the consumer logs(infinite)**

[image]

Is this a bug? Getting an exception is acceptable, but I don't want CPU usage to reach 100%.

Answer (score 1):

That's the behavior of the underlying kafka client until 0.11.0.0.

The `reconnect.backoff.ms` property was added in the 0.11.0.0 client (`CommonClientConfigs.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG`) - see [KAFKA-5766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5766) and the [kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/).

Spring Kafka 1.3.x uses the 0.11 client (and 2.0.x). Spring Kafka 2.1.x uses the current 1.0.0 client.